# Comment "Define methods that accept reusable objects to be filled in with data, rather than methods that return objects holding that data"

Tags: java, optimization

In regards to Java optimization, comment the technique "Comment "Define methods that accept reusable objects to be filled in with data, rather than methods that return objects holding that data".

Does this mean to pass to the method an existing object instead of having the method creating, setting, and returning a new instance?

source:
http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/rawtips.shtml

Comment: Where is this from? It seems like what you said is what the comment means, but I don't necessarily agree with it. The garbage collector is pretty good in cleaning up (unused objects) so I don't see how much of an optimization it really is unless we are looking at a really really large scale project.

Comment: I agree with @nbokmans, that is what it means but it doesn't mean that this is a good "optimization". Only in very rare cases it might be useful. Creating new objects is usually not a problem. Often you even do the opposite and have immutable objects on purpose - this sometimes leads to even more instances but reduces complexity.

Comment: Your reaction(s) might explain why i got curious about this point. Maybe it was relevant in previous Java/GC versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a recycling methodology.

I have a bottle. I fill the bottle with milk, my neighbour drinks it, I clean the bottle, I fill the bottle with other milk, my neighbour drinks it again.

Constantly the bottle is reused to be filled with new fresh milk, to serve the same purpose.

This is nice when you have a steady production line of data with a given set of data input and output and it never changes.
But what if I get two neighbours? I can't magically produce a new bottle, I need to add to it, go to to the shop, buy a bottle, clean the bottle, put milk in the bottle, etc...

In the end you end up with a really cumbersome eco system where you constantly have to define places that generate the recycleable objects, have a recycling pool, have checks if the recycling pool is full enough, if there are no clogs in the pathway. you end up with a lot of checks for checks for checks.

It's easier to make an object once, pass it around, then throw it away and have the garbage men clean it up. That way you only have to worry about the path way, and not about the recycling. Let the garbage man do what the garbage man does best, instead of building a recyling station. The garbage collector in java is really good. Just make sure your data objects have no references attached to it when they are done so they can be cleaned up.

Even better, have your data object short lived so they get cleaned up faster.

Comment: Could you further comment on "Even better, have your data object short lived so they get cleaned up faster" ?